# Finding all the jumps that could lead to a certain instruction with OllyDbg?

Tags: assembly, ollydbg

Is there a way, say there is an instruction to push a value on the stack, is there a way to find all the jumps that could have lead to that instruction being executed with OllyDbg?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ollydbg by default show the possible jumps to an opcode, usually if its no obfuscated code it will show you all the referenced jumps.

Now if you mean tracing an value into the stack and check all the possible opcodes that could have used it, thats pretty much not possible, tough i can think some solutions, but not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

Normally click on the instruction and ctrl+R will do if it is you are asking for. If your instruction is middle of some function then click the start of the function(push ebp, mov ebp,esp...) and do ctrl+R(Find reference selected command in context menu).